# Is it possible to get content of an XML element using Javascript to populate site content?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

My HTML has this currently hard-coded to read the status of the website and has a colored bar image attached to the CSS attribute that goes behind the status text.

```
     <tr>           

        <td id="normal_status" color="green"><b>NORMAL</b></td>

     </tr>
```

Is there a way I can have it instead of be hard-coded with `color="green"` and `<b>NORMAL</b>` and instead read from the XML file for those values?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use stylesheets? http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

Most browsers will render the XML correctly to (X)HTML when there's a stylesheet processing instruction attached.

Comment: This would require re-writing all of my sites.  Not an option.  They already use Javascript to do a few things, I am just looking to see if Javascript can also help me with what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could use spry to load the content from a xml to a html page

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/spry_creating_xml_data_set.html